# Correlation coefficient for sets with non-linear correlation

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, nonlinear

What method can I use to test if there is a correlation between two sets of data? The correlation coefficient works if there is a linear association, but if I have two sets that are clearly (visually by graph) correlated in a non-linear way, how can I test that? Is there a coefficient or a special method?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation

Comment: One small note: if you test for something because you had discovered it previously (eg, in a graph), the test is not truly valid.

Comment: What is the nature of the non-linearity? Is the relationship monotonic, eg?

Comment: no its not monotonic

Comment: Can you put the rather crucial information that it's not monotonic in your question? Can you plot the data?

Answer (score 1):

In case of non-linear correlation [Spearman's Rank-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) is one method

and one more method is called [Kendall's Tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient)

R code for Spearman's rank correlation:

```
cor(X, Y ,method= "spearman")
```

R code for Kendall's rank correlation:

```
cor(X, Y ,method= "kendall")
```